# How to rename a field in template specialization C++

Tags: c++, templates, alias, typedef, using

Okay lets say I declare

```
MyTemplatedClass<HouseClass, GardenClass> a;
```

but to access its field I need to use FirstVar and SecondVar like so

```
a.FirstVar = HouseClass();
a.SecondVar = GardenClass();
```

what I want to do is to make it more descriptive and rename those fields to something else e.g.

```
a.House = HouseClass();
a.Garden = GardenClass();
```

So I wonder if it is possible to declare something like this:

```
using MyTemplatedClass<HouseClass, GardenClass>::House = MyTemplatedClass<HouseClass, GardenClass>::FirstVar
```

So later in code, I could use House instead of FirstVar in this particular MyTemplatedClass specialization

```
MyTemplatedClass<HouseClass, GardenClass> a;
a.House = HouseClass();
```

Comment: Maybe [`std::get()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/get) does what you want?

Comment: I know how to access the field, all I want is to rename them for specific specializations for cosmetic reasons only, for example if I had a std::pair<HouseClass, GardenClass> I would like to access them using House and Garden instead of first and second

Comment: That's not possible. You would have to manually create a struct for each case that uses different names.

Comment: Why? This is clearly [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). Please [edit] your question and describe what kind of issue this approach should solve.

Comment: Why do you use std::pair in the first place if you want named fields? What are your reasons against using a simple struct?

Comment: Well, let's say it is not a pair but some custom super complicated templated class, I wouldn't want to write it every time just to rename fields

Comment: @Niyo not rely. With current data it is not clear why do you have to use `std::pair`. Now I would say just replace `std::pair` with custom `struct` which fields would have required names and you done. Do you have some container, use some STL algorithms?

Comment: Okay, forget about the pair, let's it is a templated class that has some methods that I need, instead of writing a class for each variable type I want to use template but it wouldbe useful to write some type of typedef so I could refer to its fields by different names as shown in the question